# So this is saying i have an undefined variable in my fiat object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, methods

```
var fiat = {
  make: fiat,
  model: "500",
  year: 1957,
  color: "medium Blue",
  passengers: 2,
  convertible: false,
  mileage: 88000,
  started: false,
  start: function() {
    started = true;
  },
  stop: function() {
    started = false;
  },
  drive: function() {
    if (started) {
      alert("Zoom Zoom!");
    } else {
      alert("Car needs to be started first.");
    }
  }

};
fiat.start();
fiat.drive();
```

So it keeps saying a variable is not defined. This is how it showed me to write it in the book. I also tried to say, if (fiat.started), but that didnt work either. Is there any other way to write it?

Comment: [Use `this.started` inside the methods `start`  and `stop` and `drive`.](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/z1a2g90x/)

Comment: "In the book" What book?

Answer (score 1):

`started` is undefined. It's the equivalent of writing `foo = "bar"`. Define it by using `var` or attaching it to the pre-defined `started` in the object.

If you want to make it a global variable, add `var started;` to the start of your code.

In your case, calling the function through an object property, replace `started` inside `start()` and `stop()` with `this.started`.